# How do I get different outputs each time the program is run by calling the same method in python?

Tags: python, classification

Below is the most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification method:

```
def most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(vectorizer, classifier, n=100):
        """
        Identify most important features if given a vectorizer and binary classifier. Set n to the number
        of weighted features you would like to show.
        """
        # additional stopwords to be remove
        # Open a file and read it into memory
        file = open('..\stopwords.txt')
        additional_stopwords = file.read()
        additional_stopwords = additional_stopwords.split()

        class_labels = classifier.classes_
        feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
        feature_names = [word for word in feature_names if word not in additional_stopwords]

        topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[:n]
        topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[-n:]

        # class_labels = category
        # coef = co-effecient
        # feat = most informative feature
        for coef, feat in topn_class1:
            print(class_labels[0], coef, feat)

        print()

        for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
            print(class_labels[1], coef, feat)
```

Currently, I can only print for two categories as shown above in the 2 for loops...

But I want to get 2 different categories each time the program runs... 
For instance, 1st time the program runs-> the output will be class 3 and 4 the 2nd time the program runs will be class 4 and 5 
3rd time program runs: class 5 and 6 
4th time program runs: class 6 and 7
5th time program runs: class 7 and 8
and that it will go through this cycle again

Please do help me take a look at my codes :((

Comment: You pass in an argument saying what you want. What's your actual question? What have you tried?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have tried to code the 2 for loops in the codes... but the thing is they only show me 2 classes but I would like to print other 2 different classes whenever the program runs

Comment: @MadPhysicist Like the instances I have provided in my question below the codes (that's the actual thing i want to ask)